# Restricting one user login page

Tags: php

Restrict sign as only one user at a time on a single page (admin) across the Internet.
2 administrators. admin1, admin2. When admin1 login from Germany Admin 2 will not be able to log in from Germany, USA, Switzerland etc.

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? Do you want that only one of your multiple users can log at once ?

Comment: you want to prevent other users to access that page during that session or at all?

Comment: Yes, i want to prevent other users to access that page during session. For example i am logged in Google chrome as a admin and i can login as a another admin in a Opera (web browsers). I didnt want to that happen..

Comment: @dbrumann this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: how to set this question as solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but how you'd do it would depend on your scenario as the approach, as always, depends on your exact requirements.

You need to identify if someone is already logged in, which can be done in a few ways.

You could use a specific session name for every login. When someone attempts to login, check if that session name already exists, but this makes it hard to manage problems you'll face.

**DATABASE**
You could set data in a temporary table when someone logs in, and check if this already exists when users attempt to login.
This approach would likely be better as one of the main issues you will face is knowing if someone who is logged in is no longer using the system and so someone else logging in is legitimate.

How you handle all this depends on your exact scenario though. eg perhaps this is in-house among a few users (say 5) and they all know that they must logout when they are done, otherwise no-one else can log in.

Otherwise, you could update the temporary table with activity (every time they click on or do something update the activity timestamp), and if last activity was X mins/hours ago then log the other user out and new one in.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i will try to do that with database.. thanks ;-)